# How do I get FastAPI to do SSR for Vue 3?

Tags: python, vue.js, jinja2, fastapi, server-side-rendering

According to this documentation for [Vue's SSR](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#basic-tutorial), it is possible to use node.js to render an app and return it using an express server. Is is possible to do the same with FastAPI?

Or is using [Jinja2 templates](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/) or [SPA](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#client-side-only-rendering) the only solution?

#### Problems:

- No SPA: To help with SEO
- No [SSG](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#static-hosting): Too many pages will be generated. Some need to be generated dynamically.
- No Jinja2/Python Templates: Node modules aren't built, bundled and served. All modules have to served from a remote package CDN.

I have a feeling that maybe changing the Vue 3 delimiters and then building the project and serving the files as Jinja2 templates is the solution, but I'm not sure how it would work with Vue's routers. I know the `/dist` folder can be served on the default route and then use a catchall can be used to display files that do exist.

#### Possible Solution

```py
@app.get("/", response_class=FileResponse)
def read_index(request: Request):
    index = f"{static_folder}/index.html"
    return FileResponse(index)


@app.get("/{catchall:path}", response_class=FileResponse)
def read_index(request: Request):
    path = request.path_params["catchall"]
    file = static_folder + path

    if os.path.exists(file):
        return FileResponse(file)

    index = f"{static_folder}/index.html"
    return FileResponse(index)
```

#### Questions

- If there is a way to do SSR with FastAPI and Vue 3, what is it?
- If there is no direct way, how do I combine Vue's built `/dist` with Jinja2 templates to serve dynamic pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options available, such as Nuxt.js, Quasar, and Gridsome, which provide support for SSR with FastAPI and Vue 3.

Comment: I don't think you read my question. I have already looked into Nuxt and Gridsome. They use node.js and have to spin up a separate server to render pages. I'm asking if it's possible to render with FasAPI.

Comment: NVM, I didn't realize they had a [dynamic routes](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages/#dynamic-routes) section.